# Magento v1.4.1.1 multiCall error

Tags: php, magento

I have a problem with Magento multiCall. I have a custom PHP script that updates the products at the store. The script was working successfully few years ago but then suddenly stopped.

**The error**

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1] Internal Error. Please see log for details. in /htdocs/scripts/euronics_update.php:422
Stack trace:
#0 /htdocs/scripts/euronics_update.php(422): SoapClient->__call('multiCall', Array)
#1 /htdocs/scripts/euronics_update.php(422): SoapClient->multiCall('7a7bb80602974f5...', NULL)
#2 {main}
  thrown in /htdocs/scripts/euronics_update.php on line 422
```

**My code**

```
// collect 10 products information and execute as multiCall to speed up process
        //
        //$count_calls_array++;
        $count_running_pos++;

        //if ($count_calls_array > 10 || ($count_running_pos + 1) == count($data_all))
        if (count($calls) > 3 || ($count_running_pos + 1) >= count($data_all))
        {
            //
            // store product to Magento
            //

            if ($error_counter > 0)
            {
                echo "continued after error\n";
                $error_counter = 0;
            }

            try {
                $result = $client->multiCall($session, $calls);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $error_counter = 1;
                echo "* * * " . $e->getMessage() . " * * *\n";
                //echo "error occured, trying to restart. dump:\n".var_dump($calls)."\n";
                $result = $client->multiCall($session, $calls);
                echo "error resolved\n";
            }
            echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s').'---'.$count_running_pos.' -- '.count($calls).'<br>';
            ob_flush(); 
        flush();

            // clear array
            while (count($calls) > 0)
            {
                $tmp = array_pop($calls);
            }
            //$count_calls_array = 0;
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Richard

Comment: The error message says "Please see log for details"   What does the log say?

Comment: The log only has the date and time the update was started.